# Kotlinのvalって何の略称なのでしょうか？

Tags: kotlin

varとvalがどっちがどっちなのかよくわからなくなります。語源がわかれば迷うことが少なくなると思いました。
varはvariable。ではvalは？

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**value** みたいですね(予想通りだと思いますが)。

[このページ](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/6b38tq/i_wrote_an_article_about_why_i_switched_out_java/)にこんなことが書いてありました。

> Why? Not sure the exact origins of which language did it first. But scala, which Kotlin is inspired by uses val and var.
>   Var means variable, and thus is an asisgnable reference number
>   Val means value, which has a specific meaning. For example the value of 2 does not change, ever.

[この資料](https://www.slideshare.net/sbjug/introduction-to-scala-for-java-programmers-15050372)の14ページ目にvarとvalについて記載があります。

Answer (score 3):

var: variable = 変数 = 変更できるもの
val: value = 値 = 変更できないもの

という感じでしょうか。

---

【追記】
「変更できないもの」だと誤解を招くかもしれないかと思ったので補足します。
プログラミング用語的にいうと正確には「再代入できないもの」になります。

ざっくりとコンパイラ気にせずに例をかくと

```
// varで人という変数を宣言し、最初に太郎さんが代入されています。
var 人 = 太郎
// 次に人に次郎さんを代入しました。
// 太郎さんと次郎さんは別人ですが、人という変数には代入できます。
人 = 次郎

// 一方、太郎という値をvalで宣言し、最初に太郎さんを代入すると
val 太郎 = 太郎
// 次に別人である次郎さんは代入できません。
太郎 = 次郎 // ×代入できません
// しかし、太郎さんの名前が次郎に変わることはあるかもしれません。
太郎.名前 = 次郎
```